# SQL - combine rows conditionally on the value of previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My issue I believe is best explained by using an example:

Sample Data

| SO | Customer | Product | Description | Quantity | Extension | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | xxx | 123 | Product A | 01 | 20.00 | USA |
| 02 | yyy | 456 | Product B | 02 | 25.00 | China |
| 02 | yyy | 456 | Product B | 01 | 12.50 | China |
| 02 | yyy | 789 | Product C | 01 | 50.00 | Mexico |
| 03 | zzz | 789 | Product C | 01 | 50.00 | Mexico |
| 03 | zzz | 789 | Product C | 01 | 50.00 | Mexico |

Desired output:

| SO | Customer | Product | Description | Quantity | Extension | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | xxx | 123 | Product A | 01 | 20.00 | USA |
| 02 | yyy | 456 | Product B | 03 | 37.50 | China |
| 02 | yyy | 789 | Product C | 01 | 50.00 | Mexico |
| 03 | zzz | 789 | Product C | 02 | 100.00 | Mexico |

So the key issue I'm having is grouping by the SO, then if there are duplicate lines of Product, consolidating lines into one. In the real data, there could be many lines to summarize or none at all - it could all be unique.

Comment: Isn't this just a [`SUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: sorry, having an issue with the formatting, first time poster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like `group by`:

```
select SO, Customer, Product, Description, sum(Quantity), sum(Extension),   Country
from t
group by SO, Customer, Product, Description, Country;
```

Note that `quantity` looks strange.  Numbers in SQL are not shown with leading zeros -- and numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.